# Equilibrium points of $\dot x(t)=-2\cdot x^3(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

The following differential equation is given:
$$
\dot x(t)=-2\cdot x^3(t)\qquad x(t)\in\mathbb R
$$
I am asked to find the equilibrium points of the system. By definition, the equilibrium points are:
$$
0=-2\cdot x_e^3\Rightarrow x^3_e=0\Rightarrow x_e=0 
$$
Therefore my answer is: "there is one equilibrium point, $x_e=0$". However, the answer to the question *explicitly takes points off* for mentioning just one equilibrium point. It says there are *three* equilibria: $x_{e_1}=0,x_{e_2}=0,x_{e_3}=0$. I don't understand the need for this redundancy, since in the end it's the same point. Am I missing something subtle here?

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: It's the solution to a past university exam question.

Comment: There is one steady-state solution, $x(t) = 0$. I don't understand the "book" answer any more than you do.